# Codeigniter 3 - CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Chrome browser is showing error `CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` in Codeigniter 3.0. I have used plesk panel.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>

    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: And what resource does it say doesn’t have that header?

Comment: @Quentin woff,woff2,ttf these resource doesn't have header.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.